# Using TCA9548A to read 30 ADCs

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, adc, multiplexer

I want to read 30 differential ended analog sensors.
Using ADS1115 16 bit this is possible, but we end up having only 4 address on I2C, so i chose TCA9548A breakout board with 8 I2C multiplex channels,
Is it possible to read the ADC as shown in the block diagram [image: Block Diagram]
if yes, please help with code.

Comment: based on the *datasheet* for the `tca9548a` - what you propose is possible - help, would be to google *arduino TCA9548A*

Comment: If using arduino is not essential, this post could be moved to the electrical engineering stack exchange.